# Combination with two letters together

Tags: combinatorics

I've to type of letters A and B and fill the 5 five blank spaces. And calculate in how many ways i can perform a conbinations in which AA are always together.

My first attenpt was to calculate without any condition

```
_2_ x _2_ x _2_ x _2_ x _2_ = 32 possible ways
```

Now i'm stuck with the condition of two A together ( AA )

Comment: Your 32 is correct for the case with no restriction.  For the restriction does every A have to be next to another or is AABAB acceptable?  Is AAABB acceptable?  Before the restriction is clear, it can't be calculated.

Comment: Yes AABAB is possible and AAABB is also possible, because there're two A together.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  It is easier to count the cases with all A's isolated and subtract.  There are five choices with exactly one A.  How many cases with two A's that are isolated?  How many with three?  There are none with any more.  Add them up and subtract from 32.

Added: for the general case of $n$ slots, there are a total of $2^n$ strings.  To count the number without two As together, a string of length $n$ can either be a string of length $n-1$ with a $B$ added, or a string of length $n-2$ with $BA$ added.  You should convince yourself that these are disjoint and exhaust the possibilities.  Then if $G(n)$ is the numbe of strings without two A's together, $G(n)=G(n-1)+G(n-2), G(1)=2,G(2)=3$  This is exactly the Fibonacci recurrence with the index offset by $2$.

Comment: I tried something like _A_ _A_  _2_ * _2_ * _2_ = 8 and move the A's but still very confusing, because i've to get a general formula to apply to similar cases but with diferent numbers

Comment: There are ${5 \choose 2}=10$ ways to position two A's.  I was suggesting you count the ones of those that have all the A's isolated.  This is a reasonable approach when you have few characters.  If you need a general solution, you need to think in terms of a recurrence.  There is a nice one showing that the number of strings with no pair of As together is the Fibonacci numbers offset by 1.

Comment: What do you mean by isolate the A's like this A _ A _ A _ ? I'm learning this in my own without any professional help, that's why i'm having to much dificulty i tried to search on the internet but can't find any formula or exercises that will work on my problem.

Comment: Yes, if you have two A's out of five locations, there are four places they can be and be neighbors-the first of the pair can be in the first through fourth position.  That leaves six ways you can have two As and not touch.  If you have three, there is only one way they can not touch.  So 1 (for no As)+5(for one A)+6 (for two As)+1 (for three As) makes 13 ways you can not have any As touching, so 19 you can have two As touching.